# Why is storing a value in an instance variable more expensive than looking up a hash?

Tags: ruby, performance, memoization

I ran a benchmark to see whether memoizing attributes was faster than reading from a configuration hash. The code below is an example. Can anybody explain them?

#### The Test

```
require 'benchmark'

class MyClassWithStuff
  DEFAULT_VALS = { one: '1', two: 2, three: 3, four: 4 }
  def memoized_fetch
    @value ||= DEFAULT_VALS[:one]
  end
  def straight_fetch
    DEFAULT_VALS[:one]
  end
end

TIMES = 10000
CALL_TIMES = 1000

Benchmark.bmbm do |test|
  test.report("Memoized") do
    TIMES.times do
      instance = MyClassWithStuff.new
      CALL_TIMES.times { |i| instance.memoized_fetch }
    end
  end
  test.report("Fetched") do
    TIMES.times do
      instance = MyClassWithStuff.new
      CALL_TIMES.times { |i| instance.straight_fetch }      
    end
  end
end
```

#### Results

```
Rehearsal --------------------------------------------
Memoized   1.500000   0.010000   1.510000 (  1.510230)
Fetched    1.330000   0.000000   1.330000 (  1.342800)
----------------------------------- total: 2.840000sec

               user     system      total        real
Memoized   1.440000   0.000000   1.440000 (  1.456937)
Fetched    1.260000   0.000000   1.260000 (  1.269904)
```

Comment: In both cases it returns DEFAULT_VAL[:one]. Just in case of memoized_fetch it does a check ||=. So it's a bit expensive.

Comment: Remmeber that the variable is a reference to an object, so, as Yevgieny mentioned, it always returns reference to DEFAULT_VAL[:one]. And the `memoized_fetch` has one operation more than the `straight_fetch`. For curiosity I checked the bencharks for `if-than-else` and `expr ? v1 : v2` - the `||=` operator is definitely faster.

Comment: so it's the extra `||=` call that's adding more to the time?

Comment: `a ||= b` is aequivalent to `a = b unless a; a` — so yes, it's the reason that the „Memoized“ version is slower.